# HDMI worked in another display, stopped working now on a LG!

Tags: hdmi, output, config.txt

My Raspberry Pi Model B Board works with RCA output, but do not work with HDMI, after it shows the splash screen. (curiously enough, it shows the splash screen, then a white screen with an option to press SHIFT - after that the TV shows "NO SIGNAL").

It is strange because the HDMI output worked before with another LCD TV which I don't have anymore. Now, with an LG TV the HDMI is not working, even when I change the `config.txt`, as suggested by other peopl people.

I tried uncommenting:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
config_hdmi_boost=4
```

But it didn't work! It worked when I uncommented:

```
hdmi_safe=1
```

However the resolution looked awful.  I changed the HDMI cable, I inverted the cables, I switch on the Raspberry after the TV was on and the right input (HDMI) was selected.

Could this be a resolution problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal type `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`

Edit your `config.txt` by inserting the parameters below.
The last two parameters will set your TV resolution & refresh rates, get your TV specs from the manufacturer.

Open another terminal and run the command `tvservice -m CED` for `hdmi_group=1` or `tvservice -m DMT` for `hdmi_group=2` to determine if your TV mode is in the CED or DMT group.

Then set the `hdmi_group=1` if CED and do vice versa. Note the mode number and set the `hdmi_mode=*`.

```
disable_overscan=0
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1
hdmi_ignore_cec=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=81
```